# What is causing ScribdFu::ScribdFuUploadError (Sorry, but ScribdFile #6 could not be uploaded to Scribd)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, scribd

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload a file (simple pdf-file of 200kb) in a rails-project I'm configuring right now:

> (Sorry, but ScribdFile #6 could not be uploaded to Scribd)

How can I find out what is going wrong? I'm using Windows 7.
I have the same configuration running on another system (Windows 7 as well) without any issues.

This is the full stack (if it helps):

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.9/lib/scribd_fu.rb:72:in `upload'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.9/lib/scribd_fu.rb:189:in `upload_to_scribd'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in 
>   `callback'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in 
>   `create_or_update'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2538:in `save_without_validation'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1078:in `save_without_dirty'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.1.1/lib/aasm/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:196:in `aasm_write_state'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.1.1/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:107:in `set_aasm_current_state_with_persistence'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.1.1/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:160:in `aasm_fire_event'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyist-aasm-2.1.1/lib/aasm/aasm.rb:61:in `convert!'
>   c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/models/scribd_file.rb:30:in`after_initialize'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `callback'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2441:in `initialize'
>
> c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:51:in `new'
>
> c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:51:in `create_attachment'
>
> c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:49:in `each'
>
> c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:49:in `create_attachment'
>
> c:/xampp/htdocs/lightbulb/app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:12:in `create'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `perform_action_without_filters'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_compass'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.0.24/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:44:in `dispatch_cgi'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:101:in `dispatch_cgi'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:27:in `dispatch'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
>
> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:281
>
> C:/Ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
>
> C:/Ruby/bin/mongrel_rails:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the proxy not set.

Answer (score 0):

What type file are you trying to upload? The usual issue is that the content_type isn't supported.

Comment: I'd try commenting out lines 68, and 71 through 73 in scribd_fu.rb, restart your app, then post the error message.